# Java multi-client chat server private message options

Tags: java

I am new at stackoverflow and I am sorry if this kind of a question is asked before but did a quick search and I could not find any title like mine. I am working on a multi-client chat application on Java. I was following the tutorials and I can send messages that every user in the application can see. But I wonder how to create and send a private message to a spesific user into the chat.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ChatServer {
    private int port;

    private Set<String> userNames = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<UserThread> userThreads = new HashSet<>();

    public ChatServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatServer(9999).execute();
    }

    private void execute() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
            System.out.println("Server is running");
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New user connected");
                UserThread newUser = new UserThread(socket, this);
                userThreads.add(newUser);
                newUser.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addUserName(String s) {
        this.userNames.add(s);
    }

    public void broadcast(String serverMessage, UserThread excludeUser) {
        for (UserThread aUser : userThreads) {
            if (aUser != excludeUser)
                aUser.sendMessage(serverMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is my server code.

```java
public void run() {
    Console console = System.console();
    String userName = console.readLine("Enter your username : ");
    writer.println(userName);
    String text;
    do {
        text = console.readLine("[" + userName + "]: ");
        if (text.startsWith("[")) {
            isTargeted = true;
            this.aimUserName = text.substring(text.indexOf("[") + 1, text.indexOf("]"));
            //System.out.println("Private Message to: " + aimUserName);
        } else {
            isTargeted = false;
        }
        writer.println(text);
    } while (!text.equals("bye"));

    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this code above is a part of my write thread class. As you can see, if a message starts with '[name]' part, the "name" means the user that we want to send a private message. By doing this, I can get the name of the user that I want to send a private message but I could not figure out how to broadcast this message just to that spesific user. I believe I need to configure my broadcast function in ChatServer class but I don't really know how to do. What steps should I follow?

--Edit--

I've been working on my question and I did some additions to solve my problem. First of all, I think I should share everything I have to you. I shared my ChatServer class previously. Other classes I have are:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ChatClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatClient().execute();
    }

    private void execute() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3);
            System.out.println("Connected to chat server");
            new ReadThread(socket, this).start();
            new WriteThread(socket, this).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadThread extends Thread{
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private Socket socket;
    private ChatClient client;
    public ReadThread(Socket socket, ChatClient client) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.client = client;

        InputStream input;
        try {
            input = this.socket.getInputStream();
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                String response = this.reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("\n" + response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
public class UserThread extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private ChatServer server;
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    public String userName;
    public UserThread(Socket socket, ChatServer chatServer) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.server = chatServer;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            writer = new PrintWriter(output,true);

            String userName = reader.readLine();
            this.userName = userName;
            server.addUserName(userName);
            String serverMessage = "New user connected: " + userName;
            server.broadcast(serverMessage,this);



            String clientMessage;
            do {
                clientMessage = reader.readLine();
                serverMessage = "[" + userName + "] : " + clientMessage;
                server.broadcast(serverMessage, this);      

            }while(!clientMessage.equals("bye"));



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void sendMessage(String serverMessage) {
        writer.println(serverMessage);
    }


}
```

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class WriteThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private ChatClient client;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    public WriteThread(Socket socket, ChatClient client) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.client = client;
        OutputStream output;
        try {
            output = socket.getOutputStream();
            this.writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        Console console = System.console();
        String userName = console.readLine("Enter your username : ");
        writer.println(userName);
        String text;
        do {
            text = console.readLine("[" + userName + "]: ");
            if(text.startsWith("[")){
                String aimUserName = text.substring(text.indexOf("[")+1,text.indexOf("]"));
                System.out.println("Private Message to: " + aimUserName);}
            writer.println(text);
        }while(!text.equals("bye"));

        /*do {
            text = console.readLine("[" + userName + "]: ");
            writer.println(text);
        }while(!text.equals("bye"));*/

        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

These codes work properly and I can multi-chat very clean. But while working on private chat stuff, I added to the ChatServer the line of:

```
public void privatebr(String serverMessage, String targetUserName){
        for(UserThread aUser: userThreads){
            if(aUser.userName == targetUserName)
                aUser.sendMessage(serverMessage);
        }
```

to the UserThread, I edited the part as:

```
String clientMessage;
            do {
                clientMessage = reader.readLine();
                serverMessage = "[" + userName + "] : " + clientMessage;
                if(clientMessage.startsWith("[")){
                    String targetUserName = clientMessage.substring(clientMessage.indexOf("[")+1,clientMessage.indexOf("]"));
                    serverMessage = "[" + userName + "] : " + clientMessage;
                    server.privatebr(serverMessage, targetUserName);
                }else{

                    server.broadcast(serverMessage, this);
                }


            }while(!clientMessage.equals("bye"));
```

But when I did all these edits, the normal multi-chat progress became broken where is my fault? Why everything has broken?

Comment: This isn't very orthodox but you could just send some data with the message that allows it to identify whether it's a private message or not. A really easy fix would be "[private][Salih]: hi!" and have the client `split` the message and recognize that it is private.

Comment: There is no single answer; you could take several approaches. You could have the client ignore messages with `[name]` if _name_ is not that user's name. You could have the server track names and IP addresses and respond on a _different_ socket for private messages.

Comment: I agree with @StephenP about using a different socket. This not only improves security but also allows you to easily read incoming public and private information from both sockets at the same time.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more advice given your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question! To answer the question you asked is that you should maintain a `Map` of Users to their Socket connections, so that way with DMs you can just select the user(s) that you want to message. You will also need a messaging protocol for that (see below)

...But I have to tell you that using Sockets and SocketServer classes in today's day and age is like re-inventing the wheel. The place to start in doing a chat server is using the web sockets protocol. Even under this, you will probably want to define a message protocol (like I did - I created a messaging protocol using JSON and message types, where the string message in the websocket event onMessage first gets parsed into an object)

There are implementations for supporting WS on all platforms: java, .net, python, php etc. This should be your starting point.

--- Update ---

I understand where you are coming from. To help you along in understanding Sockets / ServerSockets, here are a couple of pointers & resources

1. DatagramSockets (aka UDP): This is a different transmission protocol than the regular TCP, used by Shockwave and then Flash, and is the fundamental reason that Flash is problematic. I strongly recommend against this
2. Data & Object Input/OutputStreams: "Data" streams are Java only (can't connect to technologgy built on other platforms). Object streams are similar, except you are transporting actual whole objects through the stream (also Java only) No one* (almost no one) uses these anymore.
3. SocketException: Using java.net.[Server]Socket(s), you are likely to encounter this exception. It happens when you are waiting for more data (through a read / readLine call) on a socket, and the socket closes. It took me a long time to figure this out, but THIS EXCEPTION IS YOUR FRIEND! You get it when the connection has closed (either on the client or server side). It allows the thread that was waiting on the socket to wake up, and allows you to do whatever clean-up you need to do. SocketException is a subclass of IOException, so you may not even realize what this is. But now at least I have warned you
4. Streams vs. Writers and Readers: Writers and Readers are for interpreting raw bytes as Java characters and Strings. This is necessary, as there are multiple text formats (i.e. ascii, windows-xx, utf-8, utf-16). Readers and Writers help you read and write text in different text formats (and also interpreting Images from image formats).
5. Buffered Writers and Streams: These are for INEFFICIENT reading and writing. For writing, this means enabling you to write part of a message and not send it until you are ready. For reading, this means reading streams line by line for example rather than reading everything at one go.
6. TUS: tjacobs/io - https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ this is an old collection of Java libraries I put on SourceForge years ago, but a lot of the classes here pertain to dealing with Sockets. In particular, see SocketServerEx, DataFetcher, Main/App, Timeout, and maybe IOUtils. And of everything, really look at DataFetcher which is a lightweight threadableframework for Callback I/O listening.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: I completely agree about WebSockets … OP is following a tutorial which uses ServerSocket etc. — perhaps [this MDN topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers) would be a good place to start as an alternative.

Comment: I completely understand your thoughts about re-inventing the wheel but this is kind of my purpose :) I am trying to learn the basics of server term.  Also I am a beginner at programming I don't really know where to start understanding server systems. I found some really basic builts such like the server built I work on. I completely understand what you recommend but I want to work on this thing just a little bit more :)